# How to import images from body of DetailView and use it as thumbnail in ListView/?

Tags: python, django

I have a form that allows user to add a title and content for their posts. In content they can upload pictures using tinymce editor like:

[image]

`forms.py`:

```
class TinyMCEWidget(TinyMCE):
    def use_required_attribute(self, *args):
        return False


class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField()
    content = forms.CharField(
        widget=TinyMCEWidget(
            attrs={'required': False, 'cols': 20, 'rows': 10}
        )
    )
    image = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
            'image'
        ]
```

How do I use this picture as thumbnail in ListView. Please help me do it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

in **views.py**

```
class BlogPostList(ListView):
   model = BlogPost
```

in **urls.py**

```
path('blog-list/', BlogPostList.as_view(), name="blog-list")
```

in **`blogpost_list.html`**

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    <img src=="{{object.image.url}}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: there is no field called image in my model, there is only title and content in models.py

`object.image.url` you mean this is going to grab that image uploaded using tinymce

Comment: You haven't shown your models so I've assumed you had an `image` field.  Somehow you must be relating your loaded image to the title/content.  Whatever that relationship is, use it to show the image

Comment: Yes, I can add an image field to models and later on use it as thumbnail, but this would be very nice if I can use the uploaded images of tinymce.